# Exchange web service - add S/MIME certificate to Contacts

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, smime

I have build an application which will import/update contacts on the exchange server through EWS (exchange web service). Some of the contacts have a S/MIME certificate and I'm wondering if it is possible to add these certificates programmatically.

I have already looked into what is possible after creating a new Contact:

```
var contact = new Contact();
var certs = contact.UserSMIMECertificate; //this is only a getter
```

It seems that there is no setter for the S/MIME certificates...

Does anybody know a way to achive this?

---

If it is not possible through EWS I would be happy if someone could give me a hint how it would be done programmatically (if possible).

Comment: As I do not know your code or how you can interact with the environment, but you might be able to perform that via powershell as written [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/active-directory/424-publish-an-s-mime-certificate-to-ad-via-powershell.html). So you might build some kind of construct which is invoking the powershell here to perform that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I create the contacts as it is descripted here: [Creating contacts by using the EWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee693007(v=exchg.80).aspx). So the contacts are created only on the Exchange and not in Active Directory.

Comment: You need then to separate between Contact and Mail Contact. You can create contacts in Exchange which ARE in ActiveDirectory, so other users can use them and they will appear in the global address list (if configured correctly). Then you can create contacts in a mailfile. The way linked in your URL will create contacts in an mailfile (aka contact store).

Comment: Okay, sorry for this. I didn't know that both is possible. To be clear, my contacts are shared over a public contact folder, not the address list. That means, that there is no other chance to add the certificates to them, expect by hand with outlook?